# google maps native ionic 2 marker pixelated

Tags: cordova, google-maps, ionic2

When I put a marker with a large icon, I can not resize it, and when I put a small image it gets pixelated

```
    let icon = 'www/assets/images/car3.png';
    let position: GoogleMapsLatLng = new GoogleMapsLatLng(0,0);
    let markerOptions: GoogleMapsMarkerOptions = {
      position: position,
      icon:icon
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

you can give options to your marker.

```
let marker;

//example
let icon = {
  size: new google.maps.Size(46, 70),
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 70),
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(46, 70),
  icon: [URL]
};

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: this.map,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(
    position.lat, 
    position.lng),
    icon: icon
  });
  marker.setMap(this.map);
```

Comment: Note that I am using typescript and non-traditional javascript, and the google.maps.Point and google.maps.Size methods are not available in the native google maps plugin

Comment: it's typescript, you need import google maps on index.html and declare google above @Component "declare let google;"

Comment: It makes a lot of sense, I'll try (y)